# iOS Notification based on time of day

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have published a diet planning iOS App.  I've had users ask if they could have notifications pop up on there phone when it's time for them to eat a meal.  For example, if they set their set their wake up time on the App at 7am, every 3 hours an alert would pop up and remind them to eat, so would be 10am, 1pm, 4pm...

Currently I have not implemented push notifications.  I have been ready about iOS Push Notification Services, and I'm thinking that is there an easier way to accomplished this?  Some sort of scheduled notification.  I feel I shouldn't need any network integration to perform this fairly simple task.  Any suggestions are welcome.  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/) is exactly what you want.

From the linked documentation:

> After creating a `UILocalNotification` object, schedule it using either the `scheduleLocalNotification:` or `presentLocalNotificationNow:` method of the `UIApplication` class. The `scheduleLocalNotification:` method uses the fire date to schedule delivery; the `presentLocalNotificationNow:` method presents the notification immediately, regardless of the value of `fireDate`. You can cancel one or more local notifications using the `cancelLocalNotification:` or `cancelAllLocalNotifications` method of the `UIApplication` object.